# CakePHP3, when joining two tables (mysql): Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, join, cakephp-3.x

I'm new to programming on cakePHP. I need to join four tables, but I started by joining two of this four tables. When I try to join I get the error:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's.state_code' in 'field list'

I have tried using the alias, as shown before. I also tried using the table name.
Among the possible solutions for this problem that I've read, I already tried most of them. For example, the cache is not the problem, I have already deleted those files after updating the model database and I keep getting the same error.

This is the code on the officesController, here's where I'm getting the error:

```
public function view(){ 
    $this->loadModel('States');

    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'states',
            'alias' => 's',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'offices.state_code = s.state_code'
            )
        )    
    );

    $options['fields'] = array('offices.state_code', 'offices.office_name', 's.state_name');
    $offices = $this->Offices->find('all', $options);
    $this->set('offices',$offices);


}
```

I also tried the following piece of code, the problem with this one is that it only retrieves data from Offices table, not from State:

```
    $this->loadModel('States');

    $offices = $this->Offices->find('all',
       array('joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'states',
                    'alias' => 's',
                    'type' => 'left',
                    'foreignKey' => true,
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'offices.state_code = s.state_code')
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $this->set('offices', $offices);
```

In addition, with the code above I tried the foreignkey with both false and true values, and the result its exactly the same.
Also, I'm not sure about how to select specific fields from both tables. 
Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

SQL for offices table:

```
CREATE TABLE offices(
    office_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    office_name VARCHAR(128),
    address VARCHAR(128),
    state_code VARCHAR (5),
    PRIMARY KEY(office_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(state_code) REFERENCES states(state_code)
);
```

SQL for states table:

```
CREATE TABLE states(
    state_code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    state_name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (state_code)
);
```

Comment: Can you show both the offices and states tables? It would give a gist of what's going on.

Comment: @Rik.esh thanks for commenting on my question. I added the SQL code for both tables. If I'm missing useful information I can add it, just let me know.

Comment: have you set the relations between the tables in the related Model/Table ? Because if you have then you don't need to use the loadModel to get the data. Using find('all') will get all your related data.

Comment: Yes I have already set those relations. In OfficesTable I have $this->belongsTo('states'); and in StatesTable I have $this->hasMany('offices'); I think thats the right way, but Im not completely sure about it. I used the loadModel because I seen it in many examples, I didnt know it was not necessary to use it while having the relations. But still, the query is still not working